# Text word wrap with align justified using pure Lua script

Tags: lua, word-wrap

I know how to set word wrap and left, center and right alignment for a long text, but I am not able to make word-wrap with aligning justified according to the padding or form width. Is any chance to do it using a pure Lua script (Lua 5.3)?. Not use Love2D, Latex, or any Lua modules.

Comment: does this not answer your question? https://www.rose-hulman.edu/class/csse/csse221/200910/Projects/Markov/justification.html

Comment: "Not use Love2d, Latex, or any Lua modules". But where do you want to use the word wrap? On a command line / terminal? In a graphical context?

Comment: I want to produce it in a graphical context, for example in a Memo Line / Memo Text, or in a label or a text file. For example, I am using Cheat Engine Lua script to creating a form and a memo as a component of the form, then add some long text to the memo. I want the text in the memo with justified alignment according to the memo width.